# Efficient ways to find a value stored in a priority queue

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I'm implementing uniform cost search (UCS) using a priority queue with `std::vector` for its container. UCS occasionally or, at times, frequently, requires me to decrease a value already in the priority queue.

`std::priority_queue` doesn't appear to have such capability to (1) search for a pre-existing value already in the queue (2) adjust the value in the queue

I found an older post where someone suggested to create such capability yourself by deriving a new class and writing a linear find function, but that seems inefficient to have to traverse through the entire priority queue to search for a value.

Note that I wrote and am using my own min-max heap data structure using a vector container, but it's based off of the one in STL.

Are there more efficient ways to do this? One way I thought of is to use `std::map` along with the priority queue to keep track of indices. This adds to the memory complexity, but this method is only O(logn) time complexity, I think, where n is the size of the queue.

Comment: How big is your data set?  A linear traversal through a vector will normally beat a log N tree traversal.  This is because cache is super fast and tree structures (really any linked data structure) suffers from cache misses a majority of the time so you spend time waiting for the memory to be found.

Comment: I believe using a map to track indices will make your lookups constant, not log(n) - seems like a nice solution if you can manage the added complexity. Without some sorting you have no means of attaining a small time complexity, so you're going to be adding memory overhead no matter what. It's a much better solution than brute-force or even a sorted tree

Comment: @NathanOliver. It's hard for me to say honestly, but I'd probably say under 10^4 for my applications. How large does the data set need to be where the linear lookups outweigh the caching setbacks?

Comment: @alteredinstance Isn't a map basically binary search tree under the hood, so looksups should be log(n)?

Comment: How do you expect to be able to search for a value that can be anywhere in a container any better than O(logn)? There's no such container in the C++ library, TMK, (except for a vector's and array's index operation, of course).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I don't. I was just looking for some other ideas or to see if there's some glaring weakness with my map idea.

Comment: Sounds to me like your "priority queue" is really `std::multimap` or `std::multiset`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Why multimap instead of just map? My keys aren't mapped to multiple values, just one I believe.

Comment: Unless you're planning to never have more than value with the same priority in your "priority queue", with the map's key serving as the priority, a multimap/multiset is logically equivalent to a priority queue.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik On a similar note, when do you use a priority queue over a map and vice versa?

Comment: When one would be a better fit for the task at hand than the other. But you see, this, stackoverflow, is not a replacement for a C++ book. Map, multimaps, priority queues, are complicated things. Some are simpler than others, but overall one needs to understand how they work, in order to judge if one or the other is a better fit for something. Can't be explained in a sentence or two, here. See any good C++ book.

Comment: @lamanon That's a great point - I never knew that `std::map` was a tree and not a hash table! I looked it up and it's a self-balancing red-black tree... Interesting

Answer (score 0):

The standard heap implementation std::priority_queue doesn't provide the capability to change the priority of an item already in the queue.
You must remove it (erase) and push it again (push_back+make_heap).
This basicly costs `O(n/2)` for the removal, and then `O(n*log(n))` for reconstructing the heap.

You may have a look at [boost::heap](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/heap.html) for more specialized heap implementation allowing to change the priority of an existing item.